# How to define RAML spec to accept all URI params following a specific path

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, raml

I am defining a RAML spec for my Mule application.
This is the end point:

```
/client/{clientId}/resource/PATH1/PATH2/PATH-N
```

There can be any number of path pariables-'PATH' s-  after the /resource.

Even though this is defined in RAML as followings:

```
/client/{clientID}:  
  /resource/*:
```

This ends up with 404 error from APIKIT router when a request goes to `/clients/12/resource/abc/xyz/pqr`

I want to know followings:
1. How to define the RAML spec so that all requests having /client/{clientId}/resource/* will be accepted
2. Once the request comes, how to access the rest of PATH values

Who are not familiar with Mule,but RAML also can suggest any idea please.

Answer (score 0):

That’s not the point of RAML. You should define all your resources and methods, otherwise it’s of no use to anyone.

In Mule, if you want to listen for requests regardless of path, just use http:listener and access the path using attributes.

If you want to use RAML in Mule, use RAML to document all your resources and methods fully, then use the APIKit module in Mule to automatically generate all the flows and routing based on path for you.